# script turns page white

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this little script that suppose to +1 to a table if someone has been playing an audio file for more then 27 seconds.

The code used to worked fine until my host got hacked and my codes were messed with.

Now I have no idea what's wrong with it.
I'm not that good in jQuery. I had looked up some tutorials and do allot of guessing so I could of gotten this code to work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#audio").bind('play', function () {
        document.clock.theButton.value = "Stop";
        stopwatch(this.value);
    });

    $("#audio").bind('pause', function () {
        document.clock.theButton.value = "Start";
    });

});

var sec = -1;

function stopwatch(text) {
    sec++;
    if (sec <= 9) {
        sec = "0" + sec;
    }
    document.clock.stwa.value = sec;

    if (document.clock.stwa.value == "27") {
        $("#play").load("<?php echo 'accounts.php?id={$id}&music={$music}&add_play=1'; ?>");
    }
    if (document.clock.theButton.value == "Start") {
        window.clearTimeout(SD);
        sec = sec - 1;
        return true;
    }
    SD = window.setTimeout("stopwatch();", 1000);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#audio").bind('ended', function () {
        sec = -1;
    });
});
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined popup.js:1 Failed to load
>   resource box.anchorfree.net/insert/41.js?v=413161526
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stwa' of undefined

******* EDIT *******

I've updated the code according to your responses and i'm still having problems with the part where it's suppose to load the page. I've changed that part and added an alert so i could make sure there's nothing wrong with the php page, but i'm not even getting the alert to show up.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

  $("#audio").bind('play', function(){
document.clock.theButton.value = "Stop";
stopwatch(this.value);
  });

    $("#audio").bind('pause', function(){
document.clock.theButton.value = "Start";
  });

});

var sec = -1;
function stopwatch(text) {
   sec++;
 if (sec<=9) { sec = 0 + sec; }
   document.clock.stwa.value = sec;


  if(document.clock.stwa.value=="27"){
alert("Worked");
}
  if (document.clock.theButton.value == "Start") {
   window.clearTimeout(SD);
   sec=sec-1;
   return true; }
SD = window.setTimeout(stopwatch, 1000);
}
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#audio").bind('ended', function(){
  sec=-1;
  });
});


</script>
 <form name="clock" style="display:none;"><br />
       <input type="text" size="12" name="stwa" id="stwa" /><br />
       <input type="button" name="theButton" onClick="stopwatch(this.value);" value="Start" />
       <input type="button" value="Reset" onClick="resetIt();reset();" />
       </form>
```

Comment: A white page may be due to a JS error. What's showing up in the browser console?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined popup.js:1
Failed to load resource http://box.anchorfree.net/insert/41.js?v=413161526
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stwa' of undefined

Comment: jquery is not linked to the page

Comment: Please change `SD = window.setTimeout("stopwatch();", 1000);` to `SD = window.setTimeout(stopwatch, 1000);`

Comment: Mandeep is probably correct. $ is defined by jQuery, and your code is attempting to use it without/before loading jQuery.

Comment: Thanks! Linking the page with jquery manage to stop showing the white page but now it's seems that, that wasnt my only problem. For some reason it won't load the page "accounts.php?id={$id}&music={$music}&add_play=1" after the 27 seconds count.

Comment: Replace document.clock.stwa.value = sec; with document.clock.stwa.value = parseInt(sec);

Answer (score -1):

1 - Link jQuery to the page

2 - Replace `document.clock.stwa.value = sec;`

with `document.clock.stwa.value = parseInt(sec);`

3 - Replace `SD = window.setTimeout("stopwatch();", 1000);`

with `SD = window.setTimeout(stopwatch(), 1000);`

4 - Check in html if any input is defined with the id 'stwa' and 'theButton' inside a form 'clock', like this :

```
<form name="clock">
    <input type="text" id="stwa" name="stwa" value="00"  />
    <input type="button" id="theButton" name="theButton" value=""  />
</form>
```